# Is RIA Services still a viable option?

Tags: web-services, ria, wcf-data-services

With all of the client-side data services stuff out there?  Is RIA Services a viable option anymore?

Comment: You'll need to be a little more specific as the question is a little too general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I think RIA services is the greatest thing ever :-) It operates much more naturally as a service then WCF DataServices did and the Silverlight behavior that the Ria Context allows you with change tracking and revertibility is awesome. Plus how well it wires up all the relational stuff for you on the client side makes it super simple. But like the person said in their comments we'd have to know more about what you want it for before touting it as a viable option :-) Also the RIA authentication services are really slick as well...